# SSL is not enabled on the server

Tags: go

Trying to communicate with a postgres database with go, preparing the statement like this:

```
var stmt *sql.Stmt
var err error

stmt, err = db.Prepare(selectStatement)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("db.Prepare error: %v\n",err)
    return err
}
```

Throws the following error:

```
db.Prepare error: pq: SSL is not enabled on the server
```

Any solution ?

I can add more information, if needed.

Comment: // , I ended up getting this error in HashiCorp Vault.

Comment: @NathanBasanese , I know it was long time ago, but I solved that appending an `?sslmode=disable` on connection string.

Comment: cannot believe this is still relevant in 2021 (almost 2022!)

Answer (score 264, accepted):

You should establish DB connection without SSL encryption, like that:

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=test password=test dbname=test sslmode=disable")
```

Comment: thanks for this saving life comment.

btw: anyone knows how to set psql to support SSL for docker container?

Comment: thanks for the answer, I used sslmode=require when I connected to PostgreSQL heroku database with Microsoft Power BI

Answer (score 181):

If your data source name is a url, you will do it like this:

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://username:password@localhost/db_name?sslmode=disable")
```

`sslmode` is just added to the db url like a query parameter.

Answer (score 40):

Notice, please:

This even occurs, if you have indicated a `sslmode=disable`, but have empty other param. For example `dbname=`

For example, connection string:

`user=test password=test dbname=sslmode=disable` will **also issue this error**, because dbname is empty.

Comment: This saved me on my local dev setup, because password was empty here.

Answer (score 28):

To establish a connection without SSL, try

```
postgres://username:password@host:5432/database?sslmode=disable
```

Comment: // , I added this to my connection string, and it worked successfully. Thanks, @Harald.

Answer (score 23):

This is how I got it working:

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://{user}:{password}@{hostname}:{port}/{database-name}?sslmode=disable")
```

Answer (score 4):

when you are using `sqlx` for connection to `postgres` try this one:

```golang
import (
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main () {
  // c is my configuration struct use your own struct instead
  databseUrl := fmt.Sprintf(
        "postgres://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s?sslmode=disable",
        c.Postgres.User, c.Postgres.Password, c.Postgres.Host, c.Postgres.Port, c.Postgres.Name,
  )

  db, _ := sqlx.Open("postgres", databaseUrl)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Struct to pass the values or load it from Env or Config file.

Here is the solution,

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "log"
)

type Config struct {
    DBDriver      string
    DBSource      string
    ServerAddress string
}

func main() {

    db, err := openDB()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Databse Connection Error", err)
    }

    err = db.Ping()
    fmt.Println("Database Conn opend")

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error while Pinging Database")
    }

}

func openDB() (*sql.DB, error) {

    // Here you can populate the DB params from Env or Config file or use marshaling to fill in the values
    dbParams := Config{
        DBDriver:      "postgres",
        DBSource:      "postgres://usename:password@localhost:5432/DatabaseName?sslmode=disable",
        ServerAddress: "",
    }

    db, err := sql.Open(dbParams.DBDriver, dbParams.DBSource)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    return db, nil
}
```