# Postgres in docker - pq: SSL is not enabled on the server

Tags: postgresql, docker, chainlink

Progressing with setting up a local chainlink node following the docs. When I enter:

```
cd ~/.chainlink-kovan && docker run -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-kovan:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env smartcontract/chainlink:1.1.0 local n
```

And after entering my key store password I am given an error / WARN:

```
2022-02-02T16:47:33.598Z [WARN]  Postgres event broadcaster: reconnect attempt failed, trying again... pg/event_broadcaster.go:94 error=pq: SSL is not enabled on the server logger=EventBroadcaster
```

This then also leads to localhost:6688 returning nothing.

After googling this it seems it's an issue with SSL being enabled for postgres in docker, however I've tried many ways to fix but to no success. I can see my local postgres server has SSL enabled and tables have all been created. I am using WSL2 on Ubuntu to run the node with the Postrgres DB managed on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

Just solved this same problem, modify your postgreSQL url to something like

```
postgres://username:password@localhost/db_name?sslmode=disable
```

Reference: [SSL is not enabled on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959148/ssl-is-not-enabled-on-the-server)

Comment: Yep, and the use of the `sslmode=disable` flag is also covered in the Chainlink Running A Node Documentation([here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/running-a-chainlink-node/))