# Postgres: SSL is not enabled on the server

Tags: database, postgresql, go

Even though sslmode is set to disable, I am seeing an error when creating a database.

Here's the code snippet

```
func createDB(dbName string) error {
    // Connect to default postgres database
    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+
        "password=%s sslmode=disable",
        host, port, user, password)
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo) // This works
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // Create the new database
    _, err = db.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("CREATE DATABASE %s", dbName))
    if err != nil {
        return err // This is where its erroring out
    }
    return nil
}
```

As shown, I am setting the sslmode to disable. I am able to open the connection but the creation of the database is failing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSL is not enabled on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959148/ssl-is-not-enabled-on-the-server)

Comment: Works for me.  Maybe your password (or something else) contains special characters which are messing up the parsing of the connection string.  Please show a more complete example.

Comment: You forgot to show the exact error message.